# how do I write a SQL CASE/condition to flag if all of one field is a certain value?

Tags: sql, oracle

Basically I have a table that has an account ID, of which there can be one or many child IDs attached. See below

| Account | ID | Open or Close |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | a678 | Close |
| 123456 | b192 | Close |
| 123456 | j291 | Close |
| 543210 | l103 | Open |
| 543210 | m129 | Close |

I want to write a query that will basically act as a Y/N flag that tells me if all of the IDs for the account are "closed." So using the above data, id want the result to be something like

| Account | All Closed? |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | Yes |
| 543210 | No |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `CASE` with `MAX()` to get the result you want:

```
select
  account,
  case when max(open_or_close) = 'Close' 
       then 'Yes' else 'No' 
  end as all_closed
from t
group by account
```

Comment: Interesting, how does "MAX()" work in conjunction with that column? I was always under the impression that "MAX()" would need to be used with digits

Comment: When `MAX()` is used with strings, the strings are ordered alphabetically `A-Z` and the last one is returned. In this case `open` is greater than `close` so whenever the `open` string is present within the group it will takeover `close` and returned by `max(open_or_close)`. Very interesting trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of `Open`s grouped by `Account`, if this count is greater than 1 so it's Open.

```
select account,
  case when
  count(case when OpenorClose='Open' then 1 end) = 0 then 'Close' else 'Open' end 
  as openOrClose
from TBL
group by account
```

See the result from [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=32c7385bafca9a56bf190d5ad81523f3).